# How to check the jmat operators on Qutip?

Tags: quantum-state, qutip, quantum-optics, programming

I'm trying to reproduce this Qobject form Qutip

https://qutip.org/docs/latest/guide/guide-tensor.html#a-two-level-system-coupled-to-a-cavity-the-jaynes-cummings-model

but, I'm using  the Jmat operators

```
w0 =   1.0       # Energy splitting of the atom
w  =  1.25       # field frequency ( Cavity ) 
g  = 1.          # atom-cavity interaction strength    
M  = 10          # Photons in the cavity 
N  = 1           # Atoms 
j  = N/2.0       # Symmetric representation, should be integer? 
n  = N + 1 

a  = tensor(qeye(int(n)), destroy(M))  
# Relative Population operator
Jz = tensor(jmat(j, 'z'),qeye(M))
# Ladder Collective Operators 
Jp = tensor(jmat(j, '+'),qeye(M))
Jm = tensor(jmat(j, '-'),qeye(M))  

#Built Hamiltonian
H0 =  w0*Jz  + w*a.dag()*a 
H_JC =   (a.dag()*Jm + a*Jm.dag()) 

# Check the hamiltonian 
H_check = H0 + g* H_JC
```

I found the following issue
[image]

In my H_check there are two no-diagonal terms, is it correct?

It's bc `a.dag()*Jm == a.dag()` *sm is false, and that should be true, isn't it?
But I don't understand why.
I'm working with ladder collective operators bc I will work with the Dicke model.